# how can i convert a paragraph to a link by clicking a button in asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, jquery

In my project I have to convert a job description to a link by clicking a button in asp.net web form?When I click that link I should be able to see that paragraph?

Comment: With code behind. But whats the issue: Making a link ? Or adding text from code behind ? Or changing the display of an element ?

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to  use Anchor control inside paragraph this will work for you please try this